Popup is not displaying
If the user has made changes in the form and attempts to leave the page, a popup will appear. The popup is functioning correctly for leaving the page. However, when the user tries to switch tabs, the popup does not display, but the page gets blurred.
Form code:
@using (Html.BeginForm(action, "Campaign", method: FormMethod.Post, htmlAttributes: new { enctype = "multipart/form-data", @class = "form-horizontal col-sm-12", @id = "CampaignDetail", onkeydown = "return event.keyCode!=13", @onsubmit = "return onSubmitForm();" }))

Tab markup:
<ul class="nav nav-pills mb-10" role="tablist" style="font-size:14px" id="SummaryTab"> 
@{ 
    <li class="nav-item"> 
        <button id="btnEditCamp" type="button" class="nav-link @defaultTabActive" role="tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#tabeditcamp" aria-controls="tabeditcamp" aria-selected="true">
            <i class="fal fa-file-alt"></i> Detail
        </button> 
    </li> 

    if (!Model.Stage.Equals("RFQ")) 
    { 
        @*<li class="nav-item"> 
            <button id="btnCommentsCamp" type="button" class="nav-link" role="tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#tabcampcomment" aria-controls="tabcampcomment" aria-selected="true">
                <i class="fal fa-comment-alt-lines"></i> Comments
            </button> 
         </li>*@ 

       @if (hasAgreementsPermission)
       { 
           <li class="nav-item"> 
               <button id="btnAgreement" type="button" class="nav-link" role="tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#tabagreement" aria-controls="tabagreement" aria-selected="true">
                   <i class="fa-regular fa-handshake"></i> Agreement
               </button> 
           </li> 
       } 
       <li class="nav-item"> 
           <button id="btnAssets" type="button" class="nav-link" role="tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#tabassets" aria-controls="tabassets" aria-selected="true">
               <i class="fa-regular fa-book-font"></i> Assets
           </button> 
       </li> 

       @if (hasScriptsPermission) 
       {
           <li class="nav-item"> 
               <button id="btnScripts" type="button" class="nav-link" role="tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#tabscripts" aria-controls="tabscripts" aria-selected="true">
                   <i class="fa-regular fa-scroll"></i> Scripts
               </button> 
           </li> 
       } 

       <li class="nav-item"> 
           <button id="btnpacingschedule" type="button" class="nav-link" role="tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#pacingschedule" aria-controls="pacingschedule" aria-selected="true">
               <i class="fa-regular fa-timeline-arrow"></i> Pacing Schedule
           </button> 
       </li> 

       @if (!isVendor) { <li class="nav-item"> <button id="btnVendor" type="button" class="nav-link @defaultTabActiveVendor" role="tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#allocatedVendors" aria-controls="allocatedVendors" aria-selected="true"><i class="fal fa-users"></i> Vendor</button> </li> } @if (Model.Stage.Equals("Live") || Model.Stage.Equals("Completed") || Model.Stage.Equals("Paused")) { <li class="nav-item"> <button id="btnLeadList" type="button" class="nav-link @defaultTabActiveLeadList" role="tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#leadlist" aria-controls="leadlist" aria-selected="true"><i class="fa-regular fa-list-dropdown"></i> Lead List</button> </li> } } else { if (ViewBag.UserType == TC.Model.Entities.UserTypeMappings.Vendor) { <li class="nav-item"> <button id="btnRFQQuotations" type="button" class="nav-link" role="tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#tabrfqquotations" aria-controls="tabrfqquotations" aria-selected="true"><i class="fal fa-file-alt"></i> Quotation</button> </li> } else { <li class="nav-item"> <button id="btnRFQQuotationsClient" type="button" class="nav-link" role="tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#tabrfqallocation" aria-controls="tabrfqallocation" aria-selected="true"><i class="fal fa-file-alt"></i> Allocations</button> </li> } } <li class="nav-item"> <button id="btnLifeCycle" onclick="GetLifeCycle('@Model.Id')" type="button" class="nav-link" role="tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#tablifecycle" aria-controls="tablifecycle" aria-selected="true"><i class="fa-light fa-arrows-spin"></i> Life Cycle</button> </li> <li class="nav-item"> <button type="button" class="nav-link" role="tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#log" aria-controls="log" aria-selected="false">Log</button> </li> } </ul> $(document).ready(function () { $('button[data-bs-toggle="tab"]').on('show.bs.tab', function (e) { localStorage.setItem('activeTab', $(e.target).attr('id')); }); var activeTab = localStorage.getItem('activeTab'); if (activeTab) { $('#SummaryTab button[id="' + activeTab + '"]').click(); } }); 

Remember I am using ASP.NET Core MVC and my tabs are in partial view and my bootstraped model is in main view.
I have tried Javascript confirm event for this but still it is not working

Could you please try to format the code you're sharing ? If people can more easely read your question they'll be more inclined to answer it : Stack overflow editing help
